# Temporary files listed by lsof don't exist

Tags: command-line, web-browsing, adobe-flash

I like copying flash videos for offline viewing later. I used to do this by loading the video in the browser (Firefox or Google Chrome), then running this command to see where the flash file was being cached:

```
lsof | grep ^Google | grep folders
```

This will show all the temporary files Google Chrome has open at the moment, for example:

```
...
Google    311 mike   21u     REG       14,1    262148 17819373 /private/var/folders/zz/zzTLi2haPMrCYxEbpkwFmS+++TI/-Tmp-/.com.google.chrome.p22bCa
Google    311 mike   22u     REG       14,1      9974 17819369 /private/var/folders/zz/zzTLi2haPMrCYxEbpkwFmS+++TI/-Tmp-/.com.google.chrome.MUo4JT
Google    312 mike  txt      REG       14,1      9974 17819369 /private/var/folders/zz/zzTLi2haPMrCYxEbpkwFmS+++TI/-Tmp-/.com.google.chrome.MUo4JT
Google    312 mike  txt      REG       14,1    262148 17819373 /private/var/folders/zz/zzTLi2haPMrCYxEbpkwFmS+++TI/-Tmp-/.com.google.chrome.p22bCa
... etc
```

None of the files exist, though:

```
$ ls /private/var/folders/zz/zzTLi2haPMrCYxEbpkwFmS+++TI/-Tmp-/.com.google.chrome.p22bCa
ls: /private/var/folders/zz/zzTLi2haPMrCYxEbpkwFmS+++TI/-Tmp-/.com.google.chrome.p22bCa: No such file or directory
```

Listing the directory doesn't show any files or directories like this existing:

```
$ ls -lA /private/var/folders/zz/zzTLi2haPMrCYxEbpkwFmS+++TI/-Tmp-/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 mike  staff  102 Jul 24 18:14 TemporaryItems
srwxr-xr-x  1 mike  staff    0 Jul 24 12:10 com.apple.notify.206.32
srwxr-xr-x  1 mike  staff    0 Jul 24 12:10 com.apple.notify.206.33
drwxr-xr-x  2 mike  staff   68 Jul 24 18:25 hsperfdata_mike
```

What's going on here? Why can't I access the temporary files?

Since my goal is to copy the flash file for later viewing, is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On some unix variants, `lsof` shows files that have been deleted but are still open. More precisely, these files have a “link count” of 0, meaning that there is no directory entry (no link, i.e. no name) that leads to them, but the file data still exists. The file data will be deleted when the file is closed.

The ability of `lsof` to display files with a link count of 0 depends on the platform, and I can't find anything in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) regarding the situation on OS X. Try running `lsof +L` to see the files' link count, or `lsof +L1` to list only files with a link count of 0.

I wouldn't be surprised if the flash plugin created the file and immediately deleted in, it's a simple technique for making the data harder to obtain from outside the application. In other words, it's what the plugin author would do precisely to make it hard to do what you're trying to do. If that's what going on, you could counter it with something like [libtrash](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~marriaga/software/libtrash/) [for OSX](http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2008/Jan/msg00037.html).

Comment: This appears to be why the files are not visible with `ls`. Indeed, running `lsof +L` shows link counts of 0. Thanks for explaining this!

Comment: Immediately deleting temporary files is also a good way to make sure the files will be removed if the application crashes (or if there is a power failure).

Comment: I confirm that macOS does this; I tested under 10.6.8, 10.13.6, and 10.14.6 with `exec 3>/tmp/wibble; rm /tmp/wibble; lsof | grep wibble` (it lists it open under two processes because the pipe creates a subshell) followed by `exec 3>&-; lsof | grep wibble` (no longer listed).

Answer (score 4):

## lsof without sudo may not list all open files

Rule of thumb:

- to ensure comprehensive results from `lsof`, use `sudo`

### Example

Run the two commands below. Observe the differences in output. With privileges, expect to find many more lines.

#### Without superuser privileges

```
lsof / | grep root
```

#### Result:

```
COMMAND     PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
Spotlight   325 user_name_here  txt    REG    1,5     257996 8609539837 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NLP.framework/Versions/A/Resources/root.cache
```

#### With privileges

```
sudo lsof / | grep root
```

#### Result:

```
Password:
COMMAND     PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
launchd       1               root  cwd    DIR    1,5        928          2 /
launchd       1               root  txt    REG    1,5     345584 8624629318 /sbin/launchd
launchd       1               root  txt    REG    1,5     973824 8624630575 /usr/lib/dyld
launchd       1               root   44r   REG    1,5        358 8609644469 /private/etc/security/audit_control
launchd       1               root   46r   REG    1,5        652 8609644467 /private/etc/security/audit_class
UserEvent    60               root  cwd    DIR    1,5        928          2 /
UserEvent    60               root  txt    REG    1,5      35184 8624631345 /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent
... ...
```

Comment: In Super User, for OS X: [lsof reports no files open on external volume but it still cannot be safely unmounted](http://superuser.com/q/651264/84988)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the path in quotes?

Like this:

```
$ ls "/private/var/folders/zz/zzTLi2haPMrCYxEbpkwFmS+++TI/-Tmp-/.com.google.chrome.p22bCa"
```

Comment: The quotes don't help. I'll add to the question that listing the directory doesn't show any `.com.google.chome.*` files or directories.

Comment: I know this isn't answering your question but have you tried something like flv download? https://bitbucket.org/m.23/flv_download/wiki/Home

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
cp /proc/$pid$/fd/$fdid$
```

Where:

- `$pid$` - Process id
- `$fdid$` - File descriptor id

Process ids usually are `4` `digit` numbers.
File descriptors usually have a letter next to them (`r`, `u`, `w`, etc.).

Take this one for example:

```
Google    311 mike   22u     REG       14,1      9974 17819369 /private/var/folders/z...
```

Replace `$pid$` with 311 and `$fdid$` with 22 so that you get:

```
cp /proc/311/fd/22
```

Comment: Mac OS X doesn't have the `/proc` filesystem.