# Error: "couldn't unmount disk" keeps coming up when formatting external HD to eXFat

Tags: macos, external-disk, disk-format, exfat

I have a WD "my Passport" external HD that is currently formatted for a PC and I would like to format it to eXFAT. Every time I hit "erase" in disk util it just comes up with the error "couldn't unmount disk". Btw, I am running on Maverick. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Do you see any processes in Activity Monitor that are higher than usual with the exFAT drive attached? I am curious if there is something like Spotlight or fsck trying to access the drive in the background thus you have issues ejecting/unmounting

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same drive. I finally got it to work by rebooting from the recovery partition and formatting it using the disk utility option.

Answer (score 1):

It's proper for the operating system to not unmount a volume if there is, on the volume, an open file that can not be closed.

### Recommended reading

The [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104850/8546) to [The volume can't be ejected because it's currently in use](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/104842/8546)

- note the comment about use of *sudo*

The [Mac App Store page for *WhatsOpen*](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/whatsopen/id413165125?mt=12)

Posts that mention [What's Keeping Me?](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/products/wkm/wkm.html), e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22268/8546

There's another comparable app but at the moment I can't recall its name.