# What application is using a particular file?

Tags: file

I have some FileMaker databases being served for dev purposes and I keep bumping into occurrences where the database/file is locked and I can't make changes to it.

**How can I determine what application is touching/using this file so I can kill it?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the terminal command

> $ lsof 'Filename'

For a more detailed look at the file use

```
$ lsof | grep -f 'Filename'
```

Should give you the command that is using it and also the PID of that file

Comment: The file is named Data.fmp12, so when I cd into that directory and run lsof 'Data.fmp12', the terminal pauses a moment and then just displays another blank command prompt

Comment: [lsof without sudo may **not** produce the required output](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/76305/8546).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding sudo.  I set up a similar setup with the same file name, it would only appear if the file was open somewhere in a application.
It didn't show up until I added the sudo tough.

```
sudo lsof | grep /path/to/file/Data.fmp12
```